# CSS3 color animation doesn't fire in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome

In Chrome, I can't get a simple CSS3 *color* animation to work on an A-tag in the website I'm developing. Changing to the *background-color* property works fine though. It works in Internet Explorer and Edge.

The strangest thing is that I could **NOT** reproduce the error in JSFiddle or otherwise isolate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/5atbm42b/2/

Any ideas/tips to continue investigation? I know I can switch to jQuery animations but I might have run into a browser bug.

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.blink {
    -webkit-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -o-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 1.2em" class="blink">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

For reference, here is the computed CSS styling of my A tag as it shows in the browser's developer tools:

```css
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: blink;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-timing-function: ease;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
cursor: auto;
display: inline;
font-family: Verdana, sans;
font-size: 13.1999998092651px;
height: auto;
line-height: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
```

Comment: Can you try changing the animation name from 'blink' to something else and try?

Comment: @Rejoy, it didn't help

Comment: Note: To trigger the issue in the fiddle, Hit "Run". It works first load but not when run again ... really weird. Refreshing the page then fixes the fiddle again

Comment: @misterManSam works correctly on chrome V.44.0.2403.130 m

Comment: @maioman - Really? Weird. I can recreate the problem and have the same browser version - 44.0.2403.130 m - on windows

Comment: @misterManSam both fiddle and snippet work as expected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is the order in which the stylesheets are included on the page. In the fiddle the order is:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">`
- Custom styles

In the Stack snippet it is:

- Custom styles
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">`

So the color you are setting in your custom styles is being over-written by the bootstrap styles. To fix, `.glyphicon` can be forced to inherit the color of the `a` tag containing it by adding `.blink .glyphicon { color: inherit; }`.

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.blink {
    -webkit-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    -o-animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
    animation: blink .5s alternate infinite;
}
.blink .glyphicon {
  color: inherit; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
@keyframes blink {
    from { color: #000; }
    to { color: #f00; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 1.2em" class="blink">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It was always going to be simple :) Also, the [prefixes for the animation and keyframes are not needed.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) (only `-webkit-`) There has never been a `-ms-` prefix for CSS animation, either.

Comment: Making the glyphicon inherit it's parent color made it work. Thanks!

Comment: @maioman That is weird, I hit the issue in Version 44.0.2403.125 m and after updating still see the issue in Version 44.0.2403.130 m. Out of the browsers I tested it was only Chrome that was having difficulties though.

Comment: actually in the bootstrap.css cdn I'm downloading there's no color property for .glyphicon

Comment: @maioman Given this only effects Chrome (at least for some of us! :)), I think this is a bug. The style `.glyphicon` is using from `bootstrap.css` is the default `a` style (`a {color: #337ab7; text-decoration: none;}`). It seems that with `animation`s the initial `color` inherited from the parent `a` over-writes `color`s set in `animation`s unless you implicitly tell `.glyphicon` to inherit the `color`.